# Getting updates from Telegram channels I have joined in nodejs

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

Is there a way to receive new messages that are posted in specific Telegram channels in nodejs? I.e. something similar to the twitter streaming api.

There are two or three channels that I am interested in. I want my app, written in nodejs, to get any new messages/updates/pinnedmessages that are posted in these channels (these are channels created by others, not me). My app would then perform a certain action (not on Telegram) if the new messages that were posted in the Telegram channel meet certain conditions.

Is this possible, or does this run contrary to how Telegram works?